# Is there a difference between the ToString method and casting to string?

Tags: c#, .net

```
object o;
```

Is there any difference between `o.ToString()` and `(string) o` ?

Comment: Why do you ask? Care to explain the bigger picture?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a difference, yes. Every object has a `ToString` method, but not every object can be cast to a string.

```
int i = 10;
string s1 = i.ToString(); // OK
string s2 = (string)i;    // Compile error.

object o = 10;
string s3 = o.ToString(); // OK
string s4 = (string)o;    // Runtime error.
```

Answer (score 12):

`ToString()` raises exception when the object is `null`, `(string)` conversion doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

`object.ToString()` will convert the object into a string. If object has null value then it will throw an exception because no null value has `ToString()` method.

Whereas `(string)object` is a unboxing process of reference type to value type.
Here an `object` value is copying into new instance of string type.
If that `object` is null, it will assign null value.

Answer (score 3):

If you're after safe conversion from object to string just use:

```
string s = Convert.ToString(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes they both are very different.

`string anObjectString = (string)anObject;` is a Type cast or a Type conversion would only be successful if the type conversion is a *valid* one

`ToString()` is a method available to all the object(s) in the Framework. It is a virtual method where the default implementation returns you the Type name of the object.

We're comparing apples to oranges here..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ToString()` is a method which every type implements (since every type inherits from `System.Object` which implements the method). Certain types may override this method to provide their own custom overriding implementations. A call to `ToString()` should always succeed and return a string instance (although it may be null for some implementations).

```
var x = new AnyArbitraryObjectType();
var y = x.ToString(); // will always succeed (if ToString has not been overridden, or if it has been overridden properly)
```

A cast is the conversion of a given object reference to a reference typed as string. If the reference being cast is not a string, then the cast will fail.

```
var a = "hello";
var b = 5;

var x = (string)a; // will succeed
var y = (string)b; // will fail with InvalidCastException
```

Answer (score 0):

basically ToString() is a function that returns a string that represents the object you applied it on.

string as a type is like an int - a primitive (in c# its an object)