# Difference Between ToString() and Casting to String

Tags: c#, string, casting

```
string id = (string)result.Rows[0]["Id"];
```

Above line of code returns `InvalidCastException`. Why it is that so?

But if I change the code to this 
 
`string id = result.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();` 
 then it's working. Am I did anything wrong in my previous line of code?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565100/447156 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4152205/447156

Comment: `CAST` and `Convert` are two different concepts.

Comment: note that `.ToString` method is for all objects. it may return name of the object not the property (`id`)you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's not working because `ID` has a different Type. It's not `string` - so you can convert it but not cast it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look at different operations like if it's some dialog between you and compiler:

```
    // here you say to compiler "hey i am 100% sure that it is possible 
    // to cast this `result.Rows[0]["Id]` to string
    // this results in error if cast operation failed

    string id = (string)result.Rows[0]["Id"];


    // here you say to compiler: "please try to cast it to 
    // string but be careful as i am unsure that this is possible"
    // this results in `null` if cast operation failed

    string id = result.Rows[0]["Id"] as string;


    // here you say to compiler: "please show me the string representation of 
    // this result.Rows[0]["Id"] or whatever it is"
    // this results in invoking object.ToString() method if type of result.Rows[0]["Id"]  
    // does not override .ToString() method.

    string id = result.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess your rows' indexer's type isn't `string`. A cast looks like this:

```
(TypeA)objB
```

This is only successful when

1. `objB` is of type `TypeA`,
2. `objB` is of type `TypeC` where `TypeC` is a subclass of `TypeA`,
3. `objB` is of type `TypeC` where `TypeC` is a superclass of `TypeA` and objB's declaring type is `TypeA`.

So, your code doesn't work.

**However**, since every type derives from the holy `Object` class, every type has a `ToString` method. Thus, whatever type `Rows[0]["Id"]` returns, it has or has not a custom implementation of the `ToString` method. The type of the return value of the `ToString` method is always, you guessed it, `String`. So that's why `ToString` works.

Answer (score 1):

`ToString()` does not simply cast your object, it calls its `ToString`-method providing a "string-representation". Casting however means that the object itself IS a string and therefor you can cast it.

Also have a look here: [Casting to string versus calling ToString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565100/casting-to-string-versus-calling-tostring)

EDIT: The `ToString`-method derived from `object` can be used to give a representation of any arbitrary object.

```
MyClass 
{
    int myInt = 3;
    public override string ToString() {
        return Convert.ToString(myInt);
    }
}
```

If `ToString` is not overridden within your class, than it´s default return-value is the class´ typename.

Answer (score 0):

With ToString() you are converting the row0's Id to string but in other case your casting as string which is impossible in current scenario.